# Can I treat an unarmed strike as a "Light weapon" in terms of two-weapon fighting?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons

Player's Handbook page 195:

> **Two-weapon fighting**
>   When you take the Attack action and attack with a light
>   melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can
>   use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee
>   weapon that you're holding in the other hand. You don't
>   add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>   If either weapon has the thrown property, you
>   can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee
>   attack with it.

What if a character:

- holds a light weapon in one hand, and nothing in the other hand
- fights with bare fists (not being a monk)

Can they use the bonus action for a second attack?

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **light weapon** is specifically a weapon with the **light** property. For example, if one were to look up a *Shortsword* in the Player's Handbook, it lists "light" as one of its properties.

An unarmed strike is not a weapon, so it is not a light weapon.

Given that Two-Weapon Fighting requires a "light weapon," an unarmed strike cannot be used with the Two-Weapon Fighting feature listed in the Player's Handbook as you have cited, because an unarmed strike is not a weapon.

Comment: It might be worth noting in your answer that, otherwise,  [**unarmed strike** does count as a melee weapon attack for purposes of triggering class features.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/608776737917263872)

Comment: @LegendaryDude Sure! The more extensive version of the rule is that there are two types of attacks - a "weapon attack" and a "spell attack," which are Physical and Magical attacks, respectively (but a spell attack may be physical too) A weapon attack doesn't have to be with a weapon and a spell attack doesn't have to be with a spell. An unarmed strike is still a weapon attack. The general rule is that an attack counts as a "weapon attack" unless it explicitly tells you to make a spell attack (e.g. [Fire bolt](https://is.gd/jTSw4n)), so a punch is a melee weapon attack.